# How to draw a line with exact x and y positions?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I need to work on a drawing application by using default delegate methods touches begin and touches moved.

But when I draw a line at any point of the screen, their x and y positions are changed automatically.

Actual problem in my application is: I draw a line at one position but that line is displayed in another place.  What do I have to do to solve this problem?

My code is:

```
drawImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:nil];
///drawImage.frame=CGRectMake(0,0, 320, 380);
drawImage.frame = self.view.frame;
[self.view addSubview:drawImage];

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    NSLog(@"touches moved method");
    mouseSwiped = YES;

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];    
    CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    currentPoint.y -= 20;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
    [drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    ///[drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 380)];
    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);

    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 2.0);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), components[0],components[1],components[2],alpha);

    CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    lastPoint = currentPoint;
    ///mouseMoved++;

    mouseMoved++;

    if (mouseMoved == 10) 
    {
        NSLog(@"if mouse moved is equal to 10");
        mouseMoved = 0;
    }
    NSLog(@"touches moved method ended");
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    NSLog(@"touches Ended method starting");
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    if ([touch tapCount] == 2)
    {
        NSLog(@"touches tap count==2");
        ///drawImage.image = nil;
        return;
    }    

    if(!mouseSwiped) 
    {
        NSLog(@"not equla mouse swiped");
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
        [drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
        ///[drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 380)];
        CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
        if (tagindex==1)
        {
            NSLog(@"1111");
            CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 2.0);
        }
        CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
        CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
        CGContextFlush(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
        drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    }
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Got any code relating to where you think the problem might be?

Comment: Can you show an image that would help us understand what is happening? Or the code you are using to draw?

Comment: could you please show a part of code ?

Comment: did u tried with uibeezerpath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to substitute

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
[drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
```

with

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(drawImage.frame.size);
[self.firma.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, drawImage.frame.size.width, drawImage.frame.size.height)];
```

and if u don't have the status bar, remove: currentPoint.y -= 20;
hope this is the problem.

Comment: Actually, at begging of app its worked fine.But in my application, I added some cartoon images.At the time of adding this images as subview, this draw line positions changed. That is the problem..

Comment: so i made a game with drawing and adding images, i think that the problem is when you add the image, can you post the code that do this?